# Xcode project management: single engine - different personalized applications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

The idea is that I have an application *template* that should be customized for different clients. The main goal is to provide a number of personalized applications with almost the same functionality.

What is the best approach of Xcode project organization (and maybe management) in order to achieve the following points for each client's application:

1. Always different images set for visual elements (for controls, views, icons etc);
2. Rarely different XIB files for small UI structure modification;
3. Visual customizations - code level;
4. Small functional modifications;
5. Possibility to switch back to previous personalized versions;
6. One functional engine (e.g. search functionality);

---

At the moment, for every personalization request I create in the same project's root directory **new project file**, and corresponding **XIB files**, **images set** and **source files** (for some functional requests) directories. Each project file has a reference to the **main source files** directory (engine).

But I suppose that's not the best way to organize this type of projects.

Comment: @Joe static library represents engine itself. Ok, but what about all other things around it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a project template -- or just a zip file with the template.

first, determine where you can use (something such as) xml defs instead of overriding and other source level changes.

> Always different images set for visual elements (for controls, views, icons etc);

add placeholder resources to the project template

> Rarely different XIB files for small UI structure modification

add it to the project, referring changes (if it's changed) via vc

> Visual customizations - code level;

core libraries, shared across all projects. consider using c or c++ if the library will be large. objc cannot be stripped. this contains implementation stubs, as well as common code, base classes, and interfaces.

> Small functional modifications

extend the interface of your core classes so the subclasses may easily implement the frequent alterations. these files are part of the template.

> Possibility to switch back to previous personalized versions;

it should be in vc, and the dependency versions should also be tracked.

> One functional engine (e.g. search functionality);

an undefined factory function is simple enough:

```
id<MONSearchEngineProtocol> MONAppCoreCreateSearchEngine();
```

declare it in the static lib, but define (and implement what is necessary) in one of the project specific sources. you can add this other places - some people would stuff it in the app controller and override it.

if you have a lot of these to manage, consider moving your resources to code (rather than managing a ton of nibs). a nib defines a lot of code -- which is a lot of nearly duplicate code to manage. this will make sense for some resources, and not much sense for others.

Answer (score 10):

I'd probably choose to do this sort of thing using version control, and keep separate branches for each customised version. That way, the master/trunk can be your uncustomised code.

When you need to create a customised version, simply create another branch. If your core app needs to change, merging the changes from trunk into the branches should be straightforward, and this gives you the advantage of keeping all the customised code/files separate.

I don't know how easily this would fit into your workflow, but I think it ticks all the boxes, including being able to switch back to previous versions.

Comment: After a couple of days, I'm really surprised to see every other answer suggesting a solution either in code, or using Xcode's target system. Am I missing something? To me this seems exactly the sort of thing that a decent version control tool is built to do.

Comment: That's a whole other can of worms. My personal preference is Git, but I'm sure that Mercurial would do a decent job too, or at a push Subversion (although that isn't as good for merges IMHO).

Comment: I agree with paul. SCM is the best way in my mind. I too suggest git. If you want to use git, you can even make your "engine" a submodule. This better captures the capsulation (i.e. visual customisation isn't really a "branch" of the engine) and might be helpful in making sure changing functions in one app might be used by, but doesn't break the others.

Comment: A submodule is an excellent idea. I guess it depends how small the 'small functional modifications' are, and what code is being changed.

Answer (score 2):

Create a static library with all of your base functions. Then every project can link to this static library. It means if you find a bug you only have to fix it once, and just rebuild all client programs.

Answer (score 1):

Use Xcode's targets. You can specify different resources and/or source files to be included in one target.

If you want to have multiple code-customizations in one file, define a compiler-macro for every target and use `#ifdef MY_MACRO` to include code for that specific target.

Comment: +1 for targets (but all-in-one is not a "must"). However `#ifdef MY_MACRO` maybe is a good solution for 2-3 projects. I have 15+, and this will result in a mess :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make alot of content management by using xml for providing content. ex. if you want a image different graphics for either ipad or ipad you can create a tag something like this:

```
<MyLogo logoID="0">
<ipad image="someImage2X" height="50" width="50" position="100, 100"/>
<iphone image="someImage2" height="50" width="50" position="100, 100"/>
</MyLogo>
```

And then ofcourse create a parser for the xml. This you can create many different products of same type with different content.

Also check for device/content you are working on, and then parser to correct tag for your needs.

Hench: You can create different xml attributes for different effects, as long as you have implemented the core functionality for the effect.

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple Code Customizations in one file use - Compiler Macros (Do Define and Use).

You can use X-Code Targets but I know this won't be of much help.

I've started working on it too. :-)

Happy XCoding